# Why doesn't this printList function work for link list in C

Tags: c

Hi this is my first question on stack overflow. I am a software engineering student and I am just starting to understand linked list. I am currently just playing around to get a better understanding for linked list, so please take it easy on me. This is supposed to be a basic concept but is somewhat challenging to understand for me. Is there anyone who can please explain to me why the printList function doesn't traverse through the list for me. I have seen examples that would work but I would really like to understand why my logic isn't working for this function.

My code is down below and I am using gcc to compile my code, not really sure of that makes a difference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;

}node;


void printList(struct node *head){
    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        printf("Here\n");
        printf("%d - ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

//this will create a new node and return a new created node
//data will be set to zero
//next pointer is set to null
struct node createNode(){
    struct node temp;
    temp.data = 0;
    temp.next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

//this will add a node to the beginning of the list
//you will need to pass a new head and pass the data you want stored of type int
//this will return a type node
struct node addNode(struct node head,int data){
    struct node temp;
    struct node ptr;

    temp = createNode();
    temp.data = data;

    if(head.next == NULL){//whent the list is empty
        head = temp;
    }else{
        ptr = head;
        while(ptr.next !=NULL){
            ptr = *ptr.next;//this will traverse the list until it reaches the end
        }
            ptr.next = NULL;
            head.next = ptr.next;
    }
    printf("Added: %d\n",temp.data);
    return head;

}

int main(){

    struct node head = createNode();
    struct node *temp = &head;

    int userNum;

    while(userNum != -1){
        printf("Enter a number to add to the linked list: ");
        scanf("%d",&userNum);

        if(userNum == -1){//this will end the loop
            break;
        }else{
            addNode(*temp,userNum);
        }

    }


    printList(temp);


    return 0;
}
```

My addNode function works but I don't understand why nothing will print out for the printList().
I am using a gcc as my complier if that makes any difference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - this question has been asked many times before - I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate.  Please have a read of the [help] and [ask].

Comment: Note that in your addNode function you confusing situation of a variable that is not a pointer with a name of "ptr". I'd suggest that that is not a good idea.

Comment: "->" is legal to apply to a pointer. "." is not and if you try it the compiler will reject it. (Yes, you can apply "." to a dereferenced pointer as long as that is not also a pointer.)

Comment: Try researching what it means that C is pass by value, then come back and take a close look at your addNode function.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some problem with your addNode and createNode function. You must use '->' when you want to access pointer to struct property. And you must use '.' when you dealing with ordinary struct (not a pointer). You can use malloc for the createNode function, because you will dealing with a linked list that applied with some pointer. And in the addNode function, you can use *head instead of head in the parameter because you are dealing with pointer to struct, and you can change temp and ptr to *temp and *ptr.